# Android associate floating context menu with another menu item

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, casting, menuitem

I simply need to open another floating menu when user clicks on on a submenu item.

First i need to register that submenu item to listen to my floating menu. my submenu item is in an xml file so here i go:

```
MenuItem scan = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.Scan);
registerForContextMenu((View) scan);
```

Then I implement my floating menu in another xml file and override the following function in my activity:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
```

But my code crashes when it tries to register the `MenuItem` to listen to my context menu which itself is casted to View. I had to do that or is there any other way?